# laravel 5.6 host to cpanel on shared hosting

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

How can a host a `Laravel 5.6` app to cpanel on a shared hosting.

Can someone give me an idea

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

/*
\#########my index.php file
```

Comment: What's the significance of code snippet?

Answer (score 3):

You have two methods available, one requiring ssh access. Under no circumstances do you put your entire Laravel directory into the `public_html` directory.

### SSH Access

If you have SSH access you'll want to do the following;

- Log into your account and go to your home directory `cd ~`
- Delete the `public_html` directory
- Now you want to upload your Laravel app to `~/laravel`
- Now you need to recreate public_html as a symlink `cd ~ && ln -s laravel/public public_html`

### No SSH Access

If you don't have SSH access you'll want to do the following;

- Upload your laravel installation to somewhere like `~/laravel` (above the public_html)
- Copy the contents of the `~/laravel/public` directory to `public_html`
- Change the path to match your new destination

Your new `~/public_html/index.php` should look like the following;

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../laravel/vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Comment: I've just tried the SSH approach, which resulted in `ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘public_html/public’: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Hiroki make sure you delete `public_html` first, and then do `ln -s ~/laravel/public ~/public_html`

Answer (score 0):

after googling around i found that you have to take content of public folder which has index.php file and put it in public_html. now we have to change the content of index.php file i.e just provide the right link of app.php and autoload.php which would be `require __DIR__.'/<project_folder_name>/vendor/autoload.php'` and `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/<project_folder_name>/bootstrap/app.php';` also update your .env file and check it should work if it doesnt you have to clear cache and routes using `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan route:clear` you can do this using ssh or define the function in web.php and then hitting the link

Answer (score 0):

An easy way if your shared hosting team is very supportive for you, 
Upload your files to public_html folder, and then incase if you donot have ssh access to server, contact your hosting team and ask them to point your domain name to public_html/public folder as root folder.
And then ask them to execute following command via ssh

```
composer install
```

If you want to boost the peformance, please provide them the four commands listed in the following article.

https://www.techalyst.com/links/read/112/boosting-laravel-performance-in-production-server

Answer (score 0):

`Laravel 5.6` requires `PHP 7`.

First check your shared hosting support `PHP 7` in Cpanel (PHP Selector), if yes but you have other projects which `PHP 5` and you don't want to change default php version, then use this in `.htaccess` file

**For example:** public_html/abc/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php71 .php
```

Then `PHP 7` Work and you can work with `Laravel 5.6` on shared hosting

Answer (score 0):

```
laravel -> all laravel file

public_html -> move all folder & file on *public* file laravel to *public_html*

change your index.php on public html
require __DIR__.'/../laravel/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
```

don't forget to change your php version to 7.2

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to host on shared hosting

1. Create a subdomain on hosting and map it to a folder e.g: "abc"
2. In folder "abc" upload laravel project zip (with vendor folder) then extract it
3. Map subdomain to the public folder of laravel i.e. "abc/public".
4. Create a database & user and assign that user to the database with all privileges
5. Import the DB dump in the database created above.
6. Add DB user/password in laravel .env file.

Note: If you face any due to cache remove file config.php in directory bootstrap/cache.

Answer (score -2):

Umm. Shared hosting does NOT support php 7, which larave 5.6 depends on. Have you guys found a workaround. I have been stuck for months with laravel 4.x on bluehost.

Comment: shared hosting support all kinds of configuration you want